# Pop up screen on call arrival

Tags: integration

Can somebody please suggest me is it possible to pop up screen on salesforce when an api of salesforce is hit from remote system,actually i am integrating dialler in salesforce for which i need to pop up screen when a call comes!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. Salesforce provides open CTI library to handle this. You just need to use `screenPop()` to popup the screen.

```
sforce.opencti.screenPop({
     type: sforce.opencti.SCREENPOP_TYPE.*, //Review the arguments section.
     params: object //Depends on the SCREENPOP_TYPE. Review the arguments section.
} 
});
```

[screenPop() for Lightning Experience](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_screenpop_lex.htm)

In case of classic there is a syntax change.

```
sforce.interaction.screenPop(url:string, force:boolean, (optional) callback:function)
```

[screenPop() for Salesforce Classic](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_screenpop.htm)